# Converting Adaptive Card to a Channel

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Microsoft release a new concept of [Adaptive Cards](http://adaptivecards.io). Microsoft Bot Framework implements [Adaptive Cards in Botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards) aside of [HeroCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.herocard.html) and other message type.

When I call [Message.toMessage()](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.message.html#tomessage) on a botbuilder Message I get a JSON with `content-type application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive`

How can I convert a botbuilder Message (or an Adaptive Card JSON) to a JSON compatible with given channel (Facebook, Slack, ...) ?

- How BotFramework do ?
- How [Microsoft Visualizer](http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Facebook%20(Bot%20Framework)) do ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking.. Adaptive Cards has supports for many channels, including Slack/Facebook (though there the support is limited). Not sure what you want to convert.

Comment: If you wonder how they work: AdaptiveCards, and the visualizer, are open source: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/

Comment: Support seems VERY limitated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots. How can I convert the JSON of an Adaptive Card to make it work in Messenger ?

Comment: Whats the definition of make it work in Messenger? If you have controls in your adaptive card for example, that won't work in messenger and I doubt there is a way to convert them

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Bot Builder to build message. The Message object of BotBuilder use a proprietary JSON then convert it server side to something that Facebook Messenger understand. I'm looking for the piece of code server side. Google Action / API.ai works the same way, you have to write a piece of JSON for each platform and SDK has some helper. I don't want to write and maintain a custom JSON for each platform I assume there is a piece of code to convert a "Card" into a Messenger Card, a Slack Card, a Team Card, etc ...

Comment: This "conversion" part is probably located in the Bot Connector which is not open source, like everything which is channel-specific in the bot framework